# MySQL-how to make query for selecting opening recd issued closingbalance rate from two different table one is purchase and another is issued

Tags: mysql

I want to make a query that retrieve data from two table i.e one is purchase and another is issue.
both tables have same fields i.e icode,qty,rate,purdate and issuedate.
query of purchase is:-SELECT Dry_Purchase.Icode, Sum(Dry_Purchase.Qty) AS SumOfQty, Dry_Purchase.Rate
FROM Dry_Purchase
WHERE (((Dry_Purchase.PurDate) Between DateSerial(Year(Date()),(Month(Date())-1),21) And DateSerial(Year(Date()),Month(Date()),20)))
GROUP BY Dry_Purchase.Icode, Dry_Purchase.Rate;
output of purchase query is:
Icode   SumOfQty    Rate
11  10      13.5
11  39.5        14
19  75      79.75
19  22      80
21  54      87.45
23  15      218
24  10.5        650
8   79      33.25
8   13      34

query of issue is :- SELECT Dry_Expense.Icode, Sum(Dry_Expense.Qty) AS SumOfQty, Dry_Expense.Rate
FROM Dry_Expense
WHERE (((Dry_Expense.ExpDate) Between DateSerial(Year(Date()),(Month(Date())-1),21) And DateSerial(Year(Date()),Month(Date()),20)))
GROUP BY Dry_Expense.Icode, Dry_Expense.Rate;
output of this query is

Icode   SumOfQty    Rate
11  11.55       13
11  8.55        13.5
11  10.8        14
19  2.35        80
21  54      87.45
8   15.9        33.25

after combining above both query the output should like this
rptdate icode opening recd   issued closingbal rate
19/09/18  11   0        10    8.550  1.450     13.50
19/09/18  11   0        39.5  10.800  28.700    14.00
19/09/18  19   0        75    0.000   75       79.75
19/09/18  19   0        22    2.350   72.650   80.00
19/09/18  21   0        54    54       0       87.45
19/09/18  23   0        15    0        15      218.00
19/09/18  24   0        10.5  0        10.500  650.00
19/09/18  8    0        79.0  15.900   63.100  33.25
19/09/18  8    0        13.0   0       13.000  34.00
19/09/18  8    11.550   0     11.550   0       13.00

please help me how to make query for this output
i am trying this query
SELECT A.icode,A.qty,A.rate,A.recd as recd,B.Issued as Issue 
FROM (SELECT icode,rate,purdate,SUM(Abs(qty)) AS recd 
FROM Dry_Purchase GROUP BY icde,rate ) A,
(SELECT icode,rate,expdate,(SUM(Abs(qty)) AS Issue 
 FROM Dry_Expense GROUP BY icode,rate) B
WHERE A.icode=B.icode AND A.rate=B.rate AND
(A.purdate Between DateSerial((Year(Date()),(Month(Date())-1),21)) And DateSerial(Year(Date()),Month(Date()),20)) 
 AND B.expdate Between DateSerial((Year(Date()),(Month(Date())-1),21) And DateSerial(Year(Date()),Month(Date()),20));
please help me

Comment: what will be your output from this data

Comment: i want to in the following format:

Comment: 1,     2018/12/14,     5.000,    8.00       1,     2018/12/15,      15.000,     5.00

Comment: Your SQL is unvalid your can't mix non aggregate columnms with a aggregate column.. What is the expected output?

Comment: then i make any stored procedure for this output in MySQl

Comment: Please edit your question accordingly

Answer (score 1):

Use a sub-select to locate the minimum date, then join to the to get the row matching that date.

```
SELECT
    a.`Purdate` AS a.`Date1`, a.`Qty`, a.`Rate`
FROM `TableName` a
JOIN (SELECT MIN(`PurDate`) as `minDate`
    FROM `TableName`
    WHERE `Icode` = '1') b
  ON b.`minDate` = a.`PurDate`
WHERE a.`Icode` = '1'
```

Comment: @RamNiwas Because this query does not take ties in account.. you can get multiple records out off this query.. When PurDate is the same within the icode "group"

Answer (score -1):

Since you don't need grouping you can just order by the date column and get the first two rows.

```
SELECT PurDate, Qty, Rate FROM TableName WHERE Icode = '1' ORDER BY PurDate LIMIT 2
```

Comment: Your query is working  but it not showing result as per requirement. I modified this as  Select Top 1 Purdate, Qty, Rate From table name where icode=1 Order by Purdate DESC but  it  return  record of 2018-12-15 instead of 2018-12-14  please help me

Comment: Is it MySql or Microsoft Sql server? Also do you want a result with 6 colums or 2 rows x 3 cols?

Answer (score -1):

use corelated sub query and union

```
select A.* from    
(
select * from tablename  t1  #1st min date will return
  where t1.purdate in
        （select  min（purdate） from             
         tablename t2  where t2.icode=t1.icode
         ）
   union


    select t1.* from tablename t1 inner join
      (SELECT
        Icode
      , Purdate
FROM (
      SELECT
            @row_num :=IF(@prev_value=Icode,@row_num+1,1) AS rn
          , mp.Icode
          , mp.Purdate
          , @prev_value := Icode
      FROM tablename mp
      CROSS JOIN (SELECT @row_num :=1,  @prev_value :='') vars
      ORDER BY
            mp.Icode
          , mp.Purdate DESC
    ) d
WHERE rn = 2
) t2
 on t1.Icode=t2.Icode and t1.Purdate=t2.Purdate
) as A where A.Icode in (......)
```

Comment: @ram niwas you can check my query 1st query will return min date and 2nd query will return min date then union both

Comment: its showing LIMIT error

Comment: not used limit that i have changed

Comment: hello down voter any reason for down vote ？

Comment: @RamNiwas does not it helps ?

Comment: Sir it's first part before union is working. If possible make  query that select only one record I.e complete row of min date where  icode is supplied if I want to show record of icode 3 of min date it should be show only that record

Comment: @RamNiwas i edited my answer 2nd part and checked that is working and i combine both portion for a single so easy you can use where clause

Comment: Thanx sir for help and keen interest.  It's help me

Comment: if it helps then please accept my answer as a SO appriciation

Comment: Dear sir @Aaynul Abadin Tuhin please help me in this query. i have edited my question again